# Insert data in mysql tables

Tags: mysql

This is going to sound stupid... But I can not figure out how
to put data into tables after they are already created.  The PhyMyAdmin seems very clunky and not user friendly...

I want to create 2 tables:

**category:**
[image: which looks like this]

**products:**

[image: which looks like this]

And then in the product table, I want to add 74 images... with attributes product_id, category_id, product_name, and product_image.

How in the hell do you add information into tables... Rows, Columns,? 
How do you find this?  After tables are created?

I'm trying to do this also with a .sql file to import, but this is clunky with stupid syntax errors...

Comment: I might not have understood your question but did you try to do :- Insert into category(category_id,category_name) values(1,'Electronics')

Comment: The life of a developer is full of _Clunky_

Comment: @ANKIT GAUR.... I'll try it...

Comment: @RiggsFolly.... LoL....

Comment: I have done  INSERT INTO `product` (`product_id`, `category_id`, `product_name`, `product_image`) VALUES

Comment: And I don't understand   #1046 - No database selected... The database does exist, and so do the tables...

Comment: You can write code (ie. PHP, Java, etc.) or use a tool like phpMyAdmin.

Comment: @R.Todd add your connection.php in your question.

Comment: PHPMyAdmin *is* clunky, which is why you'll soon give up using it in favour of the command line and your favourite text editor. But you can't say it's not user-friendly; in this world, that's about as good as it gets!